# Use of undeclared identifier 'didReceiveMemoryWarning'

Tags: ios

ViewController.m:

```
- (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Free up as much memory as possible by purging chached data objects that can be recreated(or reloaded from disk) later.
     */
}
```

I'm programming in XCode 8.0 and don't know why I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I just had a bad bracket implementation. The code is right! Thanks anyway!